# Expired passport Tier 2 UKVI

Tags: working-visas

I have submitted my tier 2 application and finished my biometric. When I arrived the Visa centre in HK, the staff only took my valid passport and refused to send my expired passport and I forgot to mention that I have an expired passport. Will that be ok? Will they refuse my application because I have not submitted my expired passport. Thanks !

Comment: Did the visa application contain a question asking if you posessed (or had ever posssesed) a now-expired passport? If so, did you answer the question truthfully?

Comment: I remember there is a question asked me about "do you have any passport or travel documents".....I chicked "No" because I though it asked me "do I hold another national passport".....although I have clearly entered all my travel records and gave my valid passport, I forgot to answer that I got an expired passport...I don't think I try to lie to them..otherwise I won't ask the staff to take my expired passport and send it with my valid passport.

Comment: This seems to be a response to a comment, not an answer. It should be posted as a comment or edited into the original question.

Comment: @user17348 If you have only one nationality, and you hold only one passport, then I think you answered correctly. If the visa centre staff didn't take your expired passport, I'd conclude that's because the office your application was sent to doesn't want applicant's expired passports.